# Why is my test failing because of inclusion error for a date range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have my `User` model with the following validation and am using the Shoulda Matchers Gem ([this is the exact page for the method](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/ensure_inclusion_of_matcher.rb)):

```
validates_inclusion_of :birthday, 
  :in => Date.new(1850)..Time.now.years_ago(13).to_date, 
  :message => 'Sorry, you must be at least 13 years old to join.'
```

I'm using FactoryGirl and Rspec. I have this test for my `User` model:

```
describe "valid user age" do
  it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:birthday).in_range(13..150) }
end 

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    sequence(:first_name) { |n| "Bob#{n}" }
    sequence(:last_name) { |n| "User#{n}" }
    email { "#{first_name}@example.com" }
    birthday { Date.today - 13.years }
    password "foobarbob"
  end
end
```

Now from all of this I get the error:

```
User valid user age 
     Failure/Error: it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:birthday).in_range(13..150) }
     Did not expect errors to include "is not included in the list" when birthday is set to 12, got error:
```

Why is this the case when testing in the browser it works as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shoulda matchers check the error message in addition to the range of values.  If you look at the implementation at the link you posted, you'll see that both the low and high message default to :inclusion (the symbol used for looking up the internationalized version of the standard rails error message).

The error message check in the [allow value matcher](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb) allows the expected message to be specified as a symbol, a regexp, or a string.

You're also using a different range in your validation than you are in your test (a range of dates vs a range of ints).  I believe your test will pass if you change it to:

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:birthday).in_range(Date.new(1850)..Time.now.years_ago(13).to_date).with_message(/must be at least 13/) }
```

Comment: This is the error I get now:`Expected errors to include "Sorry, you must be at least 13 years old to join." when birthday is set to 13, got errors: ["birthday Sorry, you must be at least 13 years old to join. (13)"]
`

Comment: I believe that is just a poor error message produced by the shoulda matchers.  It should be indicating that no errors were expected when birthday was 13 but that an error was present.  I updated my answer to point out that your validation and test are using different ranges which is causing that.